# db.close() has removed but still getting "Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed" exception

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this error when retrieve multiple values from database table in AsyncTask. I have removed all `db.close()` from my code but the error still unable to fix. I need help to solve this problem.

**This the error LogCat**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:1027)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:664)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:397)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:905)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:834)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:144)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
at com.magusapp.rbc.DBAdapter.getAllData(DBAdapter.java:351)
at com.magusapp.rbc.NewLogin$Upload.doInBackground(NewLogin.java:357)
at com.magusapp.rbc.NewLogin$Upload.doInBackground(NewLogin.java:339)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 4 more
```

**This is database code sample**

```
public ArrayList<MainDetails> getAllData(String stationid, String date) {
    ArrayList<MainDetails> todos = new ArrayList<MainDetails>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS3 + " WHERE " + KEY_STATIONID + " = '" + stationid + "' AND " + KEY_DATE + " = '" + date + "'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    //error
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                MainDetails md= new MainDetails();
                md.setQuestionID(c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUESTIONID))));
                md.setStatus(c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STATUS))));
                md.setComment((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REMARK))));


                // adding to todo list
                todos.add(md);
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    return todos;
}
```

Comment: `db.close()` doesn't close the connection pool: it releases a database connection *to* the pool; so there's no reason why removing it should change this behaviour. You're doing some database operation too late in the appication's lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is also observed if you manipulate the database from multiple threads (for instance, doing something in asynchronous task and at the same time keeping GUI that also talks to the database, opening and closing the database handle to get the values displayed).

Check if the GUI does not talk to the database while your AsyncTask is running. To verify if this may be the reason, simply await the end of the task, temporarily stalling the GUI thread (or just put a few seconds delay statement after where you launch it). For sure this should not be in production but would do the job to identify the glitch in development environment.